# SQL SERVER - GROUPING and Convert Unit of measurement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by

I have given a task, but having a hard time on solving it. Hope you can help me with this.

Here is my scenario.

I have a sales table. the products are breads, cupcakes and cookies.

Here is the condition:

If I found 12 packs of cheesecake or certain product, I will convert it to 1 box.

So If I have

row1 product: cheesecake qty: 5 packs
row2 product: cheesecake qty: 5 packs
row3 product: cheesecake qty: 2 packs

I would get:

row 1 product: cheesecake qty: 1 box

As you can see form 3 rows, it becomes one row.

Would you help me how to do this?

Here is my code:

```
select 
        SoldtoPtNm,
        MatCode,
        MatDesc,
        SU,
        SUM(GrossQty) as total,
        datepart(wk, BillDt) as week,
        BillDt
from tbl_Sales_test

group by 
        SoldtoPtNm,
        MatCode,
        MatDesc,
        SU,
        GrossQty,
        BillDt
```

Right now what I get, is the quantity of the same uom. Please see screenshot for the result set.

Any hint and suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

[image: Result Set]

Comment: what happens if the cheesecake has a 4th row with 2 quantities? Will it be 1 box and 2 pcs? or 2 rows (1 box and 2 pcs), etc.?

Comment: Hi @EdgarAllanBayron! Yeah that should be two rows. The important part is that every time it counts as 12, it will be considered as 1 row. If there are excess quantity that don't sum up as 12, it will be also treated as one row. Hope my english is clear and understandable Thankyou. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say you have table:

```
ProductCode ProductDescription  ProductQty
1           Apple               19
2           Banana              1
1           Apple               2
1           Apple               4
2           Banana              10
3           Clementine          8
3           Clementine          1
4           Lemon               12
```

Query:

```
Select * into #temp from (
select ProductCode, 
       ProductDescription, 
       sum(ProductQty) / 12 as Qty,
       case when (sum(ProductQty) / 12) > 0 then 'BOX' else 'PACK' end Package
from Products
group by ProductCode, ProductDescription
union all
select ProductCode, 
       ProductDescription, 
       sum(ProductQty) % 12 as Qty,
       case when (sum(ProductQty) % 12) = 0 then 'No' else 'PACK' end Package
from Products
group by ProductCode, ProductDescription) as tmp

select * from #temp
where Package<>'No'
and Qty<>0
order by ProductCode
```

As a result I get this:

```
ProductCode ProductDescription  Qty Package
1           Apple               2   BOX
1           Apple               1   PACK
2           Banana              11  PACK
3           Clementine          9   PACK
4           Lemon               1   BOX
```

I hope this is what you are looking.

Answer (score 0):

Just the basics code, qty

```
with cte as 
( select code, sum(qty) as 'ttl'
  from table  
  group by code 
)

select code, ttl/12 as 'qty', 'box' as 'bp'
from cte where ttl >= 12 
union  
select code, ttl%12         , 'pack' 
from cte where ttl%12 > 0 
order by code, pb
```